# Reactjs - Issue Sending Dispatch to Reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on putting together a webpage with routing and I am having trouble getting redux to work. My goal is to send a GET response to the reducer but just to test the setup right now my goal is to send `true`. I can retrieve data from the redux store but I can't seem to send it and I am unsure where I might be going wrong. Here is what is supposed to happen:

1. Auth is checked in login or signup
2. App.js is wrapped in a provider
3. User can go to Cart.js and by clicking a button dispatch the value `true`
4. The can navigate to Menu.js and should be able to `console.log` the new value from the reducer
5. **My problem**: I can't seem to actually dispatch the `true` value. Nothing breaks but when I go to the Menu page, the console log shows the initial state of the reducer.
6. This has worked for me before in React Native. I'm wondering if I should be setting this up differently? or if authentication is messing things up?

Below is a sample of my code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Signup from './pages/Signup';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Menus from './pages/Menus';
import Carts from './pages/Carts';
import Orders from './pages/Orders';
import Land from './pages/Land';
import { auth } from './services/firebase';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
const store = createStore(ourReducer);


global.api = 'https://pitapal.metis-data.site'
//global.api = 'http://localhost:3008';


function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authenticated === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
    />
  )
}

function PublicRoute({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authenticated === false
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/home' />}
    />
  )
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          authenticated: true,
          loading: false,
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          authenticated: false,
          loading: false,
        });
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loading === true ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : (
      <Provider store={ store }>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Signup}></Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/home" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} component={Home}></PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path="/menus" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} component={Menus}></PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path="/carts" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} component={Carts}></PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path="/order" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} component={Orders}></PrivateRoute>
          <PublicRoute path="/signup" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} component={Signup}></PublicRoute>
          <PublicRoute path="/login" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} component={Login}></PublicRoute>
        </Switch>

      </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  carts: 'nothing'
};

const ourReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {

    case "CARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        carts: action.value
      }
      break;

  }
  return newState;
};


export default combineReducers({
  reducer: ourReducer,
});
```

**Carts.js**

```
class Carts extends Component {

    render() {
            return (
            <Container>
                <Button onClick={()=>this.props.setCart(true)}>sendToRedux</Button>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    
    const { reducer } = state
    return { reducer }
  };
  
  const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      setCart: (y) => dispatch({ type: "CARTS", value: y })
    };
  }
  

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,
    mapDispachToProps
  )(Carts);
```

****Menu.js****

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Header from "../components/Header";
    import MenuItem from '../components/MenuItem';
    import classes from './menus.module.css'
    import { auth, db } from "../services/firebase";
    import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    
    class Menu extends Component {
       
    
        render() {
    
            console.log('my carts data:', this.props.reducer.carts);
           }
    
            return (
    
                <Container>
                    welcome to menu
    
                </Container>
            );
        }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        const { reducer } = state
        return { reducer }
    };
      
    
      export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu);
```

EDIT:

here is my screenshot from Redux Devtools, this means the dispatch is definitely being sent correct?

So it seems the issue is that when I navigate a page using my header component, state gets reloaded, the entire app is relaoded. Wondering if someone knows what it might be. Below is my header component:

**Header.js**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../services/firebase';
//import "./header.css";
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
// import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
//import classes from './navbar.module.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {auth().currentUser
          ? 
            <Navbar className="fixed-top" collapseOnSelect expand="lg" style={{ backgroundColor: '#485671' }} variant="dark">
              <Navbar.Brand href="#home">PitaPal</Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">

                  <Nav.Link href="/login">Home</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="/menus">Manage my Menus</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                <Button onClick={() => auth().signOut()} variant="outline-success">Sign Out</Button>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        
          : 
            <Navbar className="fixed-top" collapseOnSelect expand="lg" style={{ backgroundColor: '#485671' }} variant="dark">
              <Navbar.Brand href="#home">PitaPal</Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="/signup">Sign Up</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                  <Nav.Link href="contact">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        }





      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any overt mistakes. Where is `Carts` rendered? Do you have the [redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) extension installed and configured? You should see the action being dispatched. I find it an invaluable tool for redux development.

Comment: i will install and check, I don't think iI do. It's a seperate component, I just edited my question so you can see. It's a page in my navbar which is imported everywhere.

Comment: Yes, the `CARTS` action is definitely dispatched, with the `true` value. Can you check the "State" section to see if your reducer updated state?

Comment: I think I see what the issue is. The reducer definitely changes data but then when I navigate to the `Carts` page state gets reloaded. I am wondering if this is because of the way I have created my Header component? I added it, perhaps you might have some insight?

Comment: Yes, the links in your header should be `Link` components from `react-router-dom` and not normal anchor tags with `href` as these will cause the app to reload. The `Header` would need to be rendered in the same `Router` component as you've defined your `Route`s in to use the same routing context.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Your `Header` is using plain anchor tags to issue navigation to your route pages which has the side-effect of also doing a page load.

## Solution

Use the `react-router-dom` `Link` component for linking.

Either specify the `as` prop of the `Nav.Link` or use `Link`

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login">Home</Nav.Link>
```

or

```
<Link to="/login">Home</Link>
```

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {auth().currentUser
          ? 
            <Navbar className="fixed-top" collapseOnSelect expand="lg" style={{ backgroundColor: '#485671' }} variant="dark">
              <Navbar.Brand href="#home">PitaPal</Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Link to="/login">Home</Link>
                  <Link to="/menus">Manage my Menus</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                <Button onClick={() => auth().signOut()} variant="outline-success">Sign Out</Button>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
          : 
            <Navbar className="fixed-top" collapseOnSelect expand="lg" style={{ backgroundColor: '#485671' }} variant="dark">
              <Navbar.Brand href="#home">PitaPal</Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                  <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                  <Link to="contact">Contact Us</Link>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```